# Cannot Enable Data API on Aurora Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We're trying to enable Data API for our Aurora Serverless Cluster which has been set up to be in our private subnets in our VPC. We've tried enabling it via the console (i.e. Modify > Select Data API > Apply Immediately). There weren't any errors on after submitting, but when we get back to the "Modify" page, the "Data API" checkbox is still unselected.
We have also tried enabling Data API as described on the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html , but the response still shows us that the HttpEndpointEnabled is still false.

My guess is that this could be related to Private Subnets or Security Groups. Any feedback is appreciated!

```
$ aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier our-database --enable-http-endpoint
{
    "DBCluster": {
        "Capacity": 8, 
        "MasterUsername": "admin", 
        "HttpEndpointEnabled": false, 
        "ReadReplicaIdentifiers": [], 
        "VpcSecurityGroups": [
            {
                "Status": "active", 
                "VpcSecurityGroupId": "sg-0a66b09ade97573f0"
            }
        ],
```

The database was created with CloudFormation if that matters

Comment: Not activating but also not throwing an error seems like it should be impossible... even if another (mis)configuration prevented you from ultimately accessing the endpoint, later, the service shouldn't really be aware of something like that at this layer.  Which region is this in?

Comment: Hi Michael, we're in eu-west-1 which I believe supports Data API =/

Comment: Yes, eu-west-1 (Ireland) is a supported region.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: It started working by itself (at least through the Console). AWS must have disabled or fixed it!

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a new AWS Serverless db based on Mysql 5.6.10a in Ireland now and can't enable Data API neither via aws UI nor via aws cli. I tried several times with no luck. One of my older databases still has Data API enabled and Query Editor is working fine there.

Answer (score 1):

Data API is available only for serverless db. Make sure you have selected "serverless" option while creating database.

I had the same problem when I was trying to create aurora-postgresql variant that doesn't have data api option. Then I selected aurora-mysql with serverless option and aws gave me option to enable http endpoint.